# Mounting a symlinked folder in vagrant & virtualbox

Tags: windows, vagrant, symlink, shared-directory

Okay, so here is my problem: 
I use vagrant with VirtualBox. The host is Windows 8.1, the guest is Ubuntu (64bit). I am trying to use a symlinked windows folder created by

```
mklink /j somefolder someotherfolder
```

as synced folder in Vagrant. In my Vagrantfile I have

```
# disable the default synced folder
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
# sync my desired folder
config.vm.synced_folder "./somefolder", "/vagrant"
```

Unfortunately this does not work, but gives the following error:

```
Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
can work properly. The command attempted was:

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`getent group vagrant | cut -d: -f3`
vagrant /vagrant
mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` vagrant /vagrant

The error output from the last command was:

stdin: is not a tty
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
```

Before you ask: Guest additions are installed, and mounting regular folders works flawlessly.

Is there a way to use symlinked directories as synced folders in vagrant with vbox?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: /j creates a junction, which is not the same as a symlink, /d creates symlinks. This may make a difference in your case, I don't know. Besides that, make sure that someOtherFolder is an absolute path and that it's visible/accessible in Windows Explorer and/or cmd.exe, stand alone and after creating the junction/symlink using the junction/symlink.

Comment: I tried both /d and /j. Unfortunately it makes no difference.

I found one way to make this work, although I am not sure I like it. It seems to work when I sync the folder with SMB (config.vm.synced_folder "./somefolder", "/vagrant", type: "smb"). Vagrant docs say that SMB support is still a bit rough around the edges, though...

Comment: Thanks, this question helped me realized that the symlink was a problem in my case. Switching to running `vagrant up` in the original directory fixed the problem for me. (Though I guess that won't help in your case.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. I couldn't get Symlinks working with vagrant but a Hardlink Clone did. I was trying to have my Dev folder in sync with Google Drive but did not want to relocate the folder.

**My Solution: Hardlink Clone**

1. **Download and install** [**Linkshell**](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html#download) for windows (and the listed prerequisite package) [ [direct Link to actual file I downloaded](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/HardLinkShellExt_X64.exe) | [direct link to prerequisite package I downloaded](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/B/4/8B42259F-5D70-43F4-AC2E-4B208FD8D66A/vcredist_x64.EXE) ] Direct link good for Windows XP64,
   Windows Vista64,
   Windows Server ,
   2003/2008/20012 64bit,
   Windows 7/8/10 64bit
2. Right click on source folder (in my case the one I copied to Google drive) and select pick link source

[image: pick link source context option]

3. In location where you want your "symlink", right click and select **Drop as -> Hardlink Clone**

[image: hardlink clone context option]

Thats what it took for me to get it working with vagrant. I originally tried as symbolic link without success.

Comment: What you described here just copies the files. Rather than ending up with a link to edit the original files, you get a full duplicate of every file that needs to be maintained separately.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the folder to where you need it from the VM, after that create the junction (or symlink) at the original location.